# Choose the right server for a React + Firebase hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web-applications

I have created a React.js + Firebase multi-user, blog, onlineshop app. Now I need to host it on a server. What are the requirements for the server? Does it need to support Javascript?
The client does not want to use Firebase hostin or Heroky, AWS or GoogleCloud they insist on Aruba.it but it does not have a plan that supports Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React production environment requires that, when a user visited the websites domain, say `myreactapp.com` then server serves them with `index.html` page, which is generated at build time and doesn't require anything related to javascript, you can serve it with any server like `serve` package or `nginx` or anything else.
you can read more about that on https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment